# Accidentally deleted yum.conf

Tags: centos, yum

I don't know what I was trying to do but I basically deleted `yum.conf`. I found an old config for yum on github but it still doesn't work. What do I do? I am using Centos 7.

Comment: Restore from your backup?

Comment: "_basically deleted `yum.conf`_" - do you mean you deleted just that file or that you've mangled it beyond repair, or that you've deleted other files too, or that you've broken permissions? Please be precise in your question as it might be important for a correct solution.

Comment: It is good manners to wait 24 hours before accepting an answer, to allow people from all timezones to get a chance.

Comment: @loa_in_: you should tell that to the two users who encouraged OP to accept the answer.

Comment: @roaima this reminds me of what first caused me to start backing up :-)

Comment: @loa_in_ no, it's good manners to accept a helpful answer that solves the problem. People from other timezones can have a crack at other questions, no point needlessly leaving stuff on the unanswered page.

Comment: From the [FAQ](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), "You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time." and "do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that answers your question well."

Comment: @hobbs I believe the important reason to wait some time is simply because sometimes the first answer does solve the problem but may have its issues. Maybe 7 hours afterwards come the really good answer. If you immediately accept way fewer people take a look at it and hence less answers are produced which means also less quality answers.

Comment: @Bakuriu and there are also times when that's clearly not true.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Although I've no idea what was originally in your `/etc/yum.conf`, try placing this generic/vanilla content in there.

```
$ cat /etc/yum.conf
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=5
bugtracker_url=http://bugs.centos.org/set_project.php?project_id=23&ref=http://b                                                                                                                     
ugs.centos.org/bug_report_page.php?category=yum
distroverpkg=centos-release
$
```

Comment: While this technically fixes the issue, it is also potentially unsafe. Copying entire critical config files from non-authoritative sources (with all due respect) should generally not be encouraged. It could also easily be incompatible with other versions of yum (older or newer). Reinstalling the correct package or at least fetching the file from it via a trusted source is a more sensible approach and applies to other pkgs.

Answer (score 7):

If you prefer to restore to the original, you can reinstall the rpm that creates the `yum.conf`.  First, find which rpm it comes from using `rpm -qf`.

On my system,

```
$ rpm -qf /etc/yum.conf 
yum-3.4.3-158.el7.centos.noarch
```

I found a copy here:

```
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/yum-3.4.3-158.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
```

To reinstall,

```
$ sudo rpm --reinstall http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/yum-3.4.3-158.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
```

Alternatively, you could download the rpm, and pick it apart using `rpm2cpio`:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/yum
$ cd /tmp/yum
$ curl http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/yum-3.4.3-158.el7.centos.noarch.rpm | rpm2cpio | cpio -idmv
```

It will now be in `/tmp/yum/etc/yum.conf`

Meanwhile, you may wish to start using [etckeeper](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-etc-with-version-control-using-etckeeper-on-centos-7), which will at *least* keep a local backup of your `/etc` in version control.

Comment: Etckeeper is litteraly the very first thing I install on a new system.